# Relational Sets for Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti-Symmetric and Transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I just want to brush up on my understanding of Relations with Sets. Specifically with this set:

$\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$

I understand Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti-Symmetric and Transitive in theory. But if it's not too much trouble, I'd like some help producing the appropriate R (relation) sets with the set above. So in a nutshell:

**Question:** What's the Relation sets for Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti-Symmetric and Transitive on the following set?:

$\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$

**Answer:**

I've got some of them solved, but will complete my answer when I've figured out the rest.

Reflexive: $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$

Symmetric: $\{?\}$

Anti-Symmetric: $\{?\}$

Transitive: $\{(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3)\}$

Comment: There is not a unique relation with any of those properties on the given set. So what do you mean by the relation set?

Comment: I mean just applying the properties of Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti-Symmetric and Transitive on the set shown above.

Comment: But properties are not something you apply. They are something you test. And the above set is not a relation.

Comment: No, that's what I'm trying to produce, see my edit.

Comment: Are you looking for examples of relations with each of the mentioned properties, on the given set?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, sorry my question is so confusing. I'm pretty new to Discrete Math.

Comment: The relation you had provided is indeed a transitive one. I'm not sure why somebody edited your example out.

Comment: I just accepted an edit and re-added the Transitive one I produced. Any help with Reflexive, Symmetric and Anti-symmetric?

Answer (score 3):

First of all find $A\times A$ wherein $A=\{1,2,3\}$. So, we have $$A\times A=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$$ Now try to choose some subset of above set as relations on $A$, since we know that every relation on $A$ has the form $R\subseteq A\times A$. For example $R_1=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is reflexive. $R_2=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ is reflexive, transitive and symmetric. Now try to find other relations according to what you have learnt about them.

Comment: Good work, Babak, as usual $\ddot\smile\;\;+1\;\;$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. :-)

Comment: $\Large \color{blue}{\bf\ddot\smile}\;\;$

Comment: You look great with that blue eyes. Anyway, I am going to the university. See you in the next hours Amy. Have a good peaceful sleep.

Comment: Have a wonderful day, Babak!